# Hive :Insert the records that are not present

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

I need to insert records into a table t1 from another table t2 such that insert only the records that are not in t2.

But when i use this query
insert into table t1 select * from t2 where id not in (select id from t1);

But I get error as

> Correlating expression cannot contain qualified column reference.

Can anybody suggest me a query to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`t2.id`

Yet another ridiculous hive limitation

```
insert into table t1 select * from t2 where t2.id not in (select id from t1);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use below command :-

```
insert into table t1 select t2.* from t2 left join t1 on t2.id=t1.id where t1.id is NULL;
```